# Knox official warranty statement from Samsung

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3, samsung-knox, warranty

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (N9005), and it has a problem with GPS. It's definitely a hardware problem, as I changed the software and did everything, software-wise, to fix it, but no use.

I would like to send it for repair, but my knox bit is 0x1. I searched A LOT... on how to reset that, and I couldn't find a clear answer. (if you know one that's working, I'd appreciate that).

**My question is:** What is Samsung's statement on knox warranty? Is it that I lose warranty on everything if my knox bit is 0x1 or just to software issues? Many people have said many different things and I'm confused! I couldn't find any official source from Samsung explaining this... could you help me find one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your warranty is void. But try this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2740340
 Its a howto for resetting knox.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could tell me the source of the information that "my warranty is void". This is the core of the question! I never saw anything official from Samsung stating that 0x1=warranty void.

Comment: Thats what the text in Odinmode says KNOX WARRANTY VOID

Comment: Thanks. But it's not clear what kind of warranty they mean. Warranty is split into multiple parts in their website. For example, batterie warranty is for only 6 months...

Comment: I have to say that I sent my phone for repair, and the repair people never mentioned a problem with warranty even though knox was 0x1.